# Use ggplot in an R function with three inputs: filename of dataframe, and two column variables of numeric data

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, plot

I would like to create an R function that takes as input:

- a dataframe of my choosing
- two columns of the dataframe containing numeric data

The output should be a scatterplot of one column variable against another, using both base R `plot` function and `ggplot`.

Here is a toy dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("choco" = 1:5,
                 "tea" = c(2,4,5,8,10),
                 "coffee" = c(0.5,2,3,1.5,2.5),
                 "sugar" = 16:20)
```

Here is the function I wrote, which doesn't work (also tried this with base R `plot` which didn't work - code not shown)

```
test <- function(Data, ing1, ing2)  {
  ggplot(Data, aes(x = ing1, y = ing2)) +
    geom_point()
}
test(Data = df, ing1 = "choco", ing2 = "tea")
```

As part of the above function, I would like to incorporate an 'if..else' statement to test whether ing1 and ing2 inputs are valid, e.g.:

```
try(test("coffee", "mint"))
```

- the above inputs should prompt a message that 'one or both of the inputs is not valid'
  I can see that using `%in%` could be the right way to do this, but I'm unsure of the syntax.

Comment: Use `aes_string()` to supply column names as strings to `ggplot()`. Use `data[[column_name]]` to use string names to extract a column from a data frame. So something like `if(!(is.numeric(Data[[ing1]]) & is.numeric(Data[[ing2]]))) stop("One or both inputs is not valid")` should work for that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  "choco" = 1:5,
  "tea" = c(2, 4, 5, 8, 10),
  "coffee" = c(0.5, 2, 3, 1.5, 2.5),
  "sugar" = 16:20
)

test <- function(Data, ing1, ing2)  {
  if (ing1 %in% names(Data)  &  ing2 %in% names(Data)) {
    ggplot(Data, aes(x = Data[, ing1], y = Data[, ing2])) +
      geom_point()
  }
  else {
    print("Both ing1, and ing2 has to be columns of data frame")
  }
}
test(Data = df, ing1 = "choco", ing2 = "sugar")
```

Regards,
Grzegorz

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work.

Comment: You are right @GregorThomas - not really tested, just highlighted, where the check codition has to be.

Comment: As opposed to being numeric, 'ing1' and 'ing2' should be character strings that correspond to the name of one of the columns in 'df'. Therefore, if ing2 = "mint" as in the example I cited above, then an error message would be the output, as "mint2" is not a column name in 'df'.

Comment: Then something like `if( ing1 %in% names(Data) &  ing2 %in% names(Data) ) {...}`

Comment: I tried your new code and it now works, many thanks.